# How to trigger an event before page reloads in cakephp or just plain php a cross platform compatible approach?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to trigger an event before a controller the action is called and even before the _construc function for that class is called.

I tried using cakephp beforeFilter, initialize and _construct method, didn't work as expected and i tried javascript code to trigger an event before the page is refreshed or reloads, but not working as expected.
Here is the code i tried.

```
$(window).on('beforeLoad unload',function(){
$.get('http://www.antlax.com/provider/terminate');
});
```

I am expecting to terminate a process before the page is reloaded, so that at any giving time, there will be only one process for that page for all clients connected to the server.

Comment: What you've shown is JavaScript code, which would have to be executed on the browser. The controller and it's constructor and action execute on the server side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)